# How do I pass an array to a function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

In Python 3.6, I am trying to build functions that take vectors as inputs and output vectors.  As a trivial example, consider the code:

```
import numpy as np

def vadd(a,b):

    res = np.array([[0,0,0]])

    res[0] = a[0]+b[0]

    res[1] = a[1]+b[1]

    res[2] = a[2]+b[2]

    return res
```

When I run this with objects of type np.array with three elements, Python returns an Index Error.  What's wrong?

Comment: Your `res` array is two dimensional; use two indices, or make it one dimensional: `np.array([0, 0, 0])`.

Comment: `res = np.array([0,0,0])` instead of `res = np.array([[0,0,0]])`

Comment: I figured it out; the hint was the IndexError.  np.array([[1,2,3]])[0] is [1,2,3] so to do operations on the elements one has to double index.  The code I posted works by prepending 0, to each index.  Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add vectors directly using `numpy`:

```
def vadd(a, b):
    return a + b
```

To be safe, you can put in an `isinstanceof`check to ensure that `a,b` are indeed `numpy` arrays.

Comment: Yes, I know.  I used the add as a simple example; what I am intending to do is much more complicated, which is my reason for wanting to define a function.  Sorry if I caused confusion!